# What does "Keep it real" mean in this context?

Tags: slang

All:

It is 9:00PM, one of my coworker said to me:"Dude, keep it real..".

I am curious about what does that means? I thought that phrase only has negative meaning( like true to urself. behave your true self,  etc.. I can not find any positive meaning about this phrase),  so I am wondering does he just tell me to relax and chill( be a REAL human and do not push myself unrealistic hard, because I started work from 8:30AM to now) or this is a ironic joke( like he does not believe I am working but just wasting time pretending working)?

Since He said that directly to me, so this makes me so confused! Im still learning English, and I do not make any misunderstanding to anyone or by anyone, please help.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell us the conversation between you or what were you doing at the time of speaking?

Comment: Probably nothing.

Comment: @Grizzly I am coding at work.

Comment: @Ricky U mean it just like a nomeaning goodbye ?

Comment: That's very passé, and thus uncool slang, so he's having a little good-natured fun with you. Next time he shows up ask him "how's it hangin', dude?" (provided there are no ladies present).  And when he leaves, you could throw some outdated slang at him (try "keep your powder dry", which is about 100 years more outdated than "keep it real".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent to "See ya later."

It has a positive connotation. You are given credit for being capable of being "real": considerate, responsible, honest, trustworthy.

Probably a step below "righteous dude" but a step above "Whazzup?"

Comment: Supporting evidence for this claim?